# Select by an IN clause but should behave like AND

Tags: mysql, sql, select, in-clause

`IN` clause works like `OR`,

```
select from table where id in (1, 2, 3)
```

ie **selects in case any of the item in group matches** (returns if id is 1, 2 or 3).

---

I need something similar, but based on two columns, and it should return only if `ColumnA` has all the values of `ColumnB`.

For eg,

```
  ColumnA         ColumnB
---------------------------
    1               a
    2               b
    3               c

    1               a
    1               b
    1               c


select CoumnA from table where CoumnA in every ColumnB of (a, b, c);
 -> 1 --since only 1 has all a, b and c

select CoumnA from table where CoumnA in every ColumnB of (b);
 -> 1 --since 1 has b
 -> 2 --since 2 has b
```

And so on. I know `in every of` is not a proper keyword, I'm just trying to show an example.

I couldn't try anything since I couldn't get my head around this logic.

Comment: @Rikesh thanks, I will see that. Sometimes searching for duplicates is almost impossible for sql type questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using just `IN(a,b,c)`
Group by id having `count(distinct id) = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
select t1.ColumnA from table t1 where 
exists (select * from table t2 where t1.ColumnA=t2.ColumnA and t2.ColumnB='a')
and exists (select * from table t2 where t1.ColumnA=t2.ColumnA and t2.ColumnB='b')
and exists (select * from table t2 where t1.ColumnA=t2.ColumnA and t2.ColumnB='c')
group by t1.ColumnA
```